# Postgres - is it possible to pull the same data back in two different orders without doubling the time taken?

Tags: postgresql, database-performance

I'm working with some postgres data that needs to be processed twice in two different orders.

Currently I select the data with one ORDER BY clause, then I run the identical query with a different ORDER BY. Obviously this takes twice as long as just running the query once!

I've tried different solutions to speed this up. First is to select the data into a temporary table, then select from the temporary table twice, once by each different sort order.

The second is two pull the data back (once) into a local data structure (a .net c# list) and then sort it (twice) locally.

The query itself is a bit of a number-cruncher. It's takes about 5 seconds to run, and produces half a dozen rows. Then I need to process the same rows in a different order - which takes another 5 seconds!

Both my solutions work ok, but neither are very elegant.

Is there a better/simpler/more elegant way?

Comment: I don’t see anything inelegant in loading data and sorting it differently client side if only thing that changes is the sorting. It’s not going to take resources with that amount of rows and to me is exactly what should be done in this case.

Comment: Maybe you could use a CURSOR? You can fetch the results forward and backward, that would fix your problem. But why do you have to proces the same records twice? And in the opposite order?

Comment: @Frank Heikens. the records need to be sorted in a different order, not the opposite order. i.e. they need to be sorted on different fields.